# How can I set correct Last-Modified header value for Spring Web Service that is cached using Spring Cache?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching, spring-cache

I have such Spring MVC Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class UserController {
   .....      
   @Cacheable(value = "users", key = "#id")
   @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   @ResponseBody
   public User getUser(Long id){
       return userService.get(id);
   }
   ....
}
```

I want to add header Last-Modified to HTTP Response of GetUser web service.
How can I get proper date when cache was added to my store?
How can I add header Last-Modified with this date to response of my Spring Controller Method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
class UserController {

    @Cacheable(value = "users", key = "#id")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(Long id) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Last-Modified", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        return new ResponseEntity<SecurityProperties.User>(headers, userService.get(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: this implementation defeats the purpose of last-modified revalidation. If the data change, the stale data will still be served from the cache with the old last-modified date

Comment: Doesn't adding `@Cacheable` to a `@RequestMapping` already defeat that purpose?

Answer (score 15):

Spring has an already build in support to handle the `last-modified` and `If-Modified-Since` header in for driven request handler methods.

It is based on [`WebRequest.checkNotModified(long lastModifiedTimestamp)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/WebRequest.html#checkNotModified-long-)

This example is just taken from the java doc:

> This will also transparently set the appropriate response headers, for both the modified case and the not-modified case. Typical usage:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String myHandleMethod(WebRequest webRequest, Model model) {
    long lastModified = // application-specific calculation
    if (request.checkNotModified(lastModified)) {
      // shortcut exit - no further processing necessary
      return null;
    }
    // further request processing, actually building content
    model.addAttribute(...);
    return "myViewName";
}
```

---

*But your `@Cacheable` annotation is a problem, because it prevent that the method is executed (for the second invocation) and therefore the `request.checkNotModified` is not invoked. - If the caching is important then you could remove the `@Cacheable` annotation from the controller method and put it on an inner method that is invoked after `request.checkNotModified` is done.*

```
 //use selfe in order to use annotation driven advices
 @Autowire
 YourController selfe;

 @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String myHandleMethod(WebRequest webRequest, Model model) {
    long lastModified = // application-specific calculation
    if (request.checkNotModified(lastModified)) {
      // shortcut exit - no further processing necessary
      return null;
    } else {  
      return selfe.innerMyHandleMethod(model);
    }
}

@Cacheable(value = "users", key = "#id")
public String innerMyHandleMethod(Model model) {   
    model.addAttribute(...);
    return "myViewName";
}
```

Comment: @dschulten: it works for annotation-based controller - I am using it!